# looping in list of strings just loop once

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings, in which i want to loop on them.. i tried to use for loop, but it only enters the loop once!

this is what i tried:

```
List<String> newsFav = <String>[];
print(newsFav.toString());
print(newsFav.length);
for(var n = 0; n < newsFav.length; n++){
 // for (var n in newsFav) {
  print(n);
...
}
```

i have tried this:

```
for(var n = 0; n < newsFav.length; n++){
```

And this:

```
for (var n in newsFav) {
```

And both didn't work! the list has two items but still it only enters once.. why?

Comment: @anmol.majhail doesn't solve the problem

Comment: what is the result of - `print(newsFav.toString());`  & `print(newsFav.length);`?

Comment: @anmol.majhail [335, 296, ] and 3 the length

Comment: your last item is an empty string - `''`, now running `for (var n in newsFav) {
  print(n);
}` - will print 335, 296,

Comment: @anmol.majhail actually it just print 335 ... its not printing the second item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197173/discussion-between-anmol-majhail-and-mrs-tat).

Comment: just open - dartpad.dartlang.org 

then run  - `void main() {
  List<String> newsFav = <String>[];
newsFav.add('326');
newsFav.add('286');
newsFav.add('');

 print(newsFav.toString());
 print(newsFav.length);
// for(var n = 0; n <= newsFav.length; n++){
//   print(n);
// }

for (var n in newsFav) {
  print(n);
}
}`

Comment: the issue could be that before running for loop your list is being edited in a way that an item is removed, so check in your code of such instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looping on an `empty list`, i guess.
`forEach` is a good format for this kind of purposes. Check the below example:

```
var list = {"a","b","c", "d", "f", "r", "t", "ty"};
  list.forEach((item) => print(item));
```

or using `for` loop only:

```
  List<String> list = ["a","b","c", "d", "f", "r", "t", "ty"];
  for(var i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
    print("Position $i : ${list[i]} ");
```

check this codes [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)
Happy `coding` :D

Comment: Since your lambda takes the same parameter as `print` you should prefer a tear-off: `list.forEach(print);`